# Регулярка: дефис, латиница и цифры?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i
```

как к регулярке добавить возможность еще и дефиса?

Comment: Может, `/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$/`? Или `/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/`. Модификатор `/i` тут не совсем к месту, `[A-Z]` будет равен `[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: Если нужно найти целую строку, состоящую из 1 и более букв, цифр или `-`, используйте `/^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$/`

Comment: Добавь примеры строк какие должны проходить проверки и какие нет

Answer (score 1):

Для добавления `-` нужно добавить его в конце группы:

```
/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]+$/i
```

Comment: нужно чтобы и такие варианты
Подходили

9-
383838

Только цифры или только дефис тоже

Comment: @werty, Добавь в вопрос примеры которые ты проверяешь. По твоему описанию непонятно что ты хочешь в итоге получить